# R error "Selenium message:Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService"

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to use RSelenium package in R on Windows 10.
Run command in cmd

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe" 
java -jar D:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
```

and run code in R

```
remDr <-　remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome",  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",  port = 4444L)  
remDr$open()
```

But I get this following error

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Selenium message:Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: '*****', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Error:   Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
Detail: A new session could not be created.
Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I downloaded Chrome(V66),The Chrome Webdriver(2.37),The Selenium Stand Alone Driver(3.11.0),all these are new version ,updated lately.
But I still get that error.Could someone please explain to me why?

Answer (score 2):

issue solved.Command in cmd should be like the following code

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe" -jar D:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
```

Comment: Hello, installing the package RSelenium doesn't yield to a directory called Selenium with chromedriver.exe in it for me ! Did you install Selenium  separately? ifo so could you guide me to do so as well please? thanks in advance

Comment: added the parameter -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe" and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this very same issue- which got resolved by including -'chromeDriver.exe' path in command used for registering node.
like- >java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -hub http://XX.XXX.XX:4444/grid/register

Answer (score 0):

I have seen more than one answer working for different people across different posts/threads.

In my case, deleting the binman folders at

[C:\Users\ your window account \AppData\Local\binman]

Worked for me, per the suggestion at
https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/146#issuecomment-357419592

After deleting the files, the error changed, but now I was able to make RSelenium work with `browser = "firefox"` instead of `browser = "chrome"`.

So, this doesn't directly solves the issue, but it does the work.